# Applescript - If file is in folder don't duplicate

Tags: file, if-statement, applescript, directory

I'm trying to test if a file from on folder path, exists in a different folder using this script:

```
set middfilesECON211 to ("/Volumes/middfiles/Classes/Spring14/ECON0211B/HANDOUTS" as POSIX file)
set gDriveECON211 to ("/Users/paolob/Google Drive/Spring 2014/ECON 211/Handouts" as POSIX file)

tell application "Finder"
   set foo to every file of folder middfilesECON211
   repeat with i from 1 to (length of foo)
       if not (exists (item i of foo) is in files of folder gDriveECON211) then
         duplicate (item i of foo) to gDriveECON211
       end if
   end repeat
end tell
```

I've tried a bunch of variation in the `if not (exists) ...` clause, but to no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[applescript]duplicate+files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set dir1 to POSIX file "/tmp/a"
set dir2 to POSIX file "/tmp/b"
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get items of folder dir1)
        if not (exists file (name of f) of folder dir2) then
            duplicate f to folder dir2 without replacing
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

You can also use `cp -n`:

```
do shell script "cp -nR /tmp/a/ /tmp/b"
```

Or `rsync --ignore-existing`:

```
do shell script "rsync -r --ignore-existing /tmp/a/ /tmp/b"
```

Comment: +1, but should we worry about what `man cp` says about `-r`? `Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
 supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.`